# How to manage certificate renewal using win-acme if the folder doesn't exist anymore?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

win-acme auto renews SSL certificate by invoking task scheduler task which executes `C:\Users\admin\Downloads\win-acme.v2.2.5.1541.x64.pluggable\wacs.exe`

Someone deleted that folder from the downloads directory. What is the way to reconfigure automatic renewal and not have the wacs.exe in downloads folder? Is the solution to download win-acme (same version), place it in another path (like C or D drive), and update the scheduled task action path?

Or does the wacs exe need running post download to auto-fix this?